# How to call a method with self parameter on a button in python

Tags: python, tkinter, inheritance, methods, self

I want to clear the text in entry widget when I click Clear button. But instead I get the TypeError: clear() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.
And again I want to get the text from entry widget for further calculations when I click Save button.
Please show me the way..

mainframe.py

```
from tkinter import Frame

class MainFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
    def show(self):
        self.lift()
```

customer_details.py

```
from tkinter import Frame, Entry, StringVar
from mainframe import MainFrame

class CustomerDetails(MainFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MainFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.var_e = StringVar(None)

        f1 = Frame(self)
        f1.pack()

        e = Entry(f1, textvariable=self.var_e)
        e.pack()
```

operations.py

```
from tkinter import Frame, Button
from mainframe import MainFrame
from customer_details import CustomerDetails

class Operations(MainFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MainFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def clear(self):
            self.var_e.set('')

        def save(self):
            self.var_e.get()

        f2 = Frame(self)
        f2.pack()

        b1 = Button(f2, text='Clear', command=clear) # I am unable to call clear function here.
        b1.pack()
        
        b2 = Button(f2, text='Save', command=save)
        b2.pack()
```

main.py

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from customer_details import CustomerDetails
from operations import Operations

class main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        f3 = Frame(self)
        f3.pack()

        customer_details_win = CustomerDetails(self)
        operations_win = Operations(self)

        customer_details_win.pack(in_ = f3)
        operations_win.pack(in_ = f3)
        
        customer_details_win.show()
        operations_win.show()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution while working on my code.
If anyone having the same issue, the code for operation.py should be as follows.
(If someone wants to know what exactly is happening in the code below please look for the tutorials on Inheritance in OOP, python)

```py
from tkinter import Frame, Button
from mainframe import MainFrame
from customer_details import CustomerDetails

class Operations(CustomerDetails, MainFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MainFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        f2 = Frame(self)
        f2.pack()

        b1 = Button(f2, text='Clear', command=self.clear)
        b1.pack()
        
        b2 = Button(f2, text='Save', command=self.save)
        b2.pack()

    def clear(self):
        self.var_e.set('')

    def save(self):
        self.var_e.get()
```

Because of these changes in operation.py, the main.py will change accordingly.

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from customer_details import CustomerDetails
from operations import Operations

class main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        f3 = Frame(self)
        f3.pack()

        operations_win = Operations(self)
        operations_win.pack(in_ = f3)
        operations_win.show()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the button b1 in operations.py, try changing the command parameter to self.clear. That will automatically send the parameter self. `b1 = Button(f2, text = "clear", command = self.clear)` I noticed that the functions clear and save are both in **init** so if you unindent them both, and move them to after the **init** function, it should work. [image]

```
from mainframe import MainFrame
from customer_details import CustomerDetails

class Operations(MainFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MainFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        f2 = Frame(self)
        f2.pack()

        b1 = Button(f2, text='Clear', command=MainFrame.clear) # I am unable to call clear function here.
        b1.pack()
        
        b2 = Button(f2, text='Save', command=save)
        b2.pack()

    def clear(self):
        self.var_e.set('')

    def save(self):
        self.var_e.get()
```

Comment: Specifically, `clear` is an ordinary function that takes one argument; `self.clear` is a bound method that takes zero arguments, as required by the button callback. The bound method stores references to both `self` and `clear`, so that it can call `self.clear()` when it itself is called.

Comment: @user14197059, I tried that it says AttributeError: 'Operations' object has no attribute 'clear'.

Comment: @MilindKhobragade Unindent the code for `clear` and `save` once.

Comment: @MilindKhobragade Also I suggest you look at a object oriented programming tutorial that focuses on python.

Comment: I think this should work now, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @TheLizzard, By doing that my operations window doesn't show when I run the code.

Comment: @user14197059 sorry, but how?

Comment: @user14197059 Tried it but it says AttributeError: type object 'MainFrame' has no attribute 'clear'.